# Using Heroku for production

Tags: heroku, ghost-blog

This help site (http://www.howtoinstallghost.com/how-to-install-ghost-on-heroku/) says that "Heroku should not be used for production!". What could the possible reasons for them saying this be?
I just want to set up a simple blog.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the same page;

> Why do you only recommend Heroku for testing?
>
> If you upload any images to your Ghost blog hosted on Heroku they will eventually be lost because of the [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). There is no warning about this so we do not currently recommend anybody to use Heroku.

In other words, since any files you write to the file system at Heroku may go away at any time (and is not shared between instances of the blog if you try to scale out), you may lose *all* uploaded pictures at any time (once a month/once a minute, who knows) and need to upload them again.

Comment: What if I host the images elsewhere, like S3? Also, what if I push the images physically instead of uploading via the interface?